# Sintaxis correcta para background-image dentro de un <div> en HTML

Tags: html

Estoy tratando de mostrar una imagen dentro de un div para usarlo como fondo y mostrar infromación sobre el fondo.

```html
<div style="background-image: url('https://www.yucatanalamano.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/cdn.expansion.mx_-97.jpg')">
</div>
```

Comment: Disculpa, la trate de poner como ejemplo para saber si de la manera que utilizo las comillas simples y las comillas dobles es la manera correcta, pero ya lo edite, gracias.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La forma de poner la imagen es la correcta, no debería darte ningún error. El problema está en el div, no has especificado tamaño y, aunque te lo dibuja con la imagen de fondo, no lo muestra porque su ancho y largo es 0. Trata de ponerle un tamaño.

```html
<div style="background-image: url('https://www.yucatanalamano.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/cdn.expansion.mx_-97.jpg'); width: 200px; height: 200px">
</div>
```

Con eso debería verse perfectamente.

Como dato curioso: También funciona si no le pones comillas en la url, creo que no es una buena práctica pero a mí nunca me ha dado problemas y puede venirte bien si en un código más extenso tienes problemas con las comillas.

`background-image: url(URLIMAGENSINCOMILLAS)`

Answer (score 3):

Las comillas están bien utilizadas... lo único que debes hacer es agregar contenido a tu div para que se refleje la imagen

```html
<div style="background-image: url('https://www.yucatanalamano.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/cdn.expansion.mx_-97.jpg');color:white">
  <br>CONTENIDO
  <br>CONTENIDO  
  <br>CONTENIDO
  <br>CONTENIDO
  <br>CONTENIDO
  <br>CONTENIDO
  <br>CONTENIDO  
  <br>CONTENIDO
  <br>CONTENIDO
  <br>CONTENIDO
  <br>CONTENIDO
  <br>CONTENIDO  
  <br>CONTENIDO
  <br>CONTENIDO
  <br>CONTENIDO
  <br>CONTENIDO
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Hola @ARR la "imagen" a la que haces referencia en realidad es una redirección a la pagina de la cual supongo intentas obtener la imagen. Me imagino que la buscaste en Google Images y diste click derecho en copiar enlace. Te sugiero mejor dar click en "Ver imagen" y después, copeas la url de la imagen de la barra de direcciones de tu navegador. De preferencia fijate bien que la url termine en .png, .jpg, .jpeg, .svg, .gif, etc. Saludos!